# Very slow hostname lookup times

Tags: ubuntu, dns, digital-ocean

On my server (DigitalOcean), it seems using hostnames for anything is very slow compared to ip addresses

For example, if I do `ping yahoo.com`, it takes a while till I start seeing information, whereas if I do `ping 206.190.36.45`, I see the results right away. The ping times themselves are the same either way.

A similar effect happens with mysql connections, curl queries, and so on

It's Ubuntu 12.04 in case that makes a difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are having trouble with the name resolver.
Look at the file `/etc/resolv.conf`
In that file your resolver is configured. 
Usually it will be your provider's recursive DNS server (we do it that way by default in our client's servers) . 
If the provider's DNS is slow on answering you always can setup your own recursive DNS server or use google's

First try to use google's server. Put

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

into /etc/resolv.conf 
It should be the only text in that file.

Check the performance. If it doesn't satisfy you setup your own recursive DNS server.

```
sudo apt-get install -y pdns-recursor && /etc/init.d/pdns-recursor restart
```

Than put

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

into /etc/resolv.conf

Now all you DNS queries will be served by your own DNS recursor.

Comment: That did it... the resolv.conf did have nameserver 8.8.8.8 in it, but had a 4.2.2.2 entry before it. Making it *only* 8.8.8.8 fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!  I had this issue after changing ISPs and this fixed it.